# React, not able to consume value inside context, getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Home page isn't rendering anything. I've checked `Home.js` and I can't find what could be the issue. In the console this is the error I get:

```
Home.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation'
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext'
import UserContext from './UserContext'
import Home from './Home'

function App() {
  let [theme, setTheme] = useState({
    variant: 'dark',
    toggleTheme: toggleTheme
  })

  let [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "Alyssa"
  })

  function toggleTheme() {
    setTheme(theme => (
      {
        ...theme,
        variant: theme.variant === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark',
      }
    ))
  }

return (
  <>
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
    <Navigation />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
    <Home />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
  
  </>
)
}
export default App
```

Home.js:

```
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert'
import UserContext from './UserContext'
import { useContext } from 'react'

function Home() {
  let user = useContext(UserContext)

  return (
    <>
    <UserContext.Consumer>
      <Alert variant="success">Welcome back, {user.name}!</Alert>
      <Card className="text-center col-md-10 mx-auto my-3">
        <Card.Header>Featured</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>This is Our Featured Item</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Click Here</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </UserContext.Consumer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the user to be consumed by a child component. You need to wrap the Home page with the UserContext.Provider and pass the user that you'd like to provide. Also, you can remove the UserContext.Consumer tag in the Home page since you are using the Hooks approach for consuming from a context.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation'
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext'
import UserContext from './UserContext'
import Home from './Home'

function App() {
  let [theme, setTheme] = useState({
    variant: 'dark',
    toggleTheme: toggleTheme
  })

  let [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "Alyssa"
  })

  function toggleTheme() {
    setTheme(theme => (
      {
        ...theme,
        variant: theme.variant === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark',
      }
    ))
  }

return (
  <>
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
    <Navigation />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
  <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
    <Home />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
  </UserContext.Provider>
  </>
)
}
export default App
```

Home

```
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert'
import UserContext from './UserContext'
import { useContext } from 'react'

function Home() {
  let user = useContext(UserContext)

  return (
    <>
      <Alert variant="success">Welcome back, {user.name}!</Alert>
      <Card className="text-center col-md-10 mx-auto my-3">
        <Card.Header>Featured</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>This is Our Featured Item</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Click Here</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Is it better to wrap usercontext.provider to cover it all because user object can be used in navigation files

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass  in  and then you can access it using props.name in Home.js file also pass props in Home.js function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's because this line `let user = useContext(UserContext)` is storing `undefined` inside `user`, which is normal because you didn't wrap `Home` inside `UserContext.Provider` and gave `user` inside `App` as value.

Change the return inside `App` to this:

```
return (
  <>
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
    <Navigation />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
  <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
    <Home />
  </UserContext.Provider>
  
  </>
)
```

And you could simplify your return inside `Home` to this:

```
return (
    <>
      <Alert variant="success">Welcome back, {user.name}!</Alert>
      <Card className="text-center col-md-10 mx-auto my-3">
        <Card.Header>Featured</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>This is Our Featured Item</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Click Here</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You didnt wrap app component with UserContext.Provider so there is no value for user object. Try this

```
<UserContext.Provider value={user}>
<ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
    <Navigation />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
    <Home />
  </ThemeContext.Provider
</UserContext.Provider>
```

And use optional chaning or and operator to access user object to prevent errors when user is null or undefined

```
{user && user.name }
```

Or

```
{user?.name}
```

Comment: I prefer to use and operator because you definelty need user object more than one place